# JFrog Container Registry 7.3.2 won't work with Active Directory

Tags: docker, active-directory, ldap, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I was hoping someone here could help me out. We are currently evaluating JFrog's Artifactory - Container Registry running as a Docker service and for the life of me I cannot get this thing to work properly with our Active Directory instance. I had it working fine in version 6 but with the release of version 7, decided to start new with the new version.

So I have artifactory-jcr:7.3.2 up and running in our swarm. Go into administration -> security -> LDAP and create a new LDAP settings profile with the following fields:

LDAP URL: **ldap://mydc.company.net:389/DC=company,DC=net**

User DN Pattern: *blank*

Email Attribute: **mail**

Search Filter: **(sAMAccountName={0})**

Search Base: **OU=Company Users**

Search Sub-Tree: **checked**

Manager DN: **CN=_svcAccount,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Company Users,DC=company,DC=net**

Manager Password: ***Correct Password***

The Manager DN is correct and the password has been verified and tested. I can log in with the service account from any machine and successfully query the directory using ADExplorer and issue a query for my account using only my `sAMAccountName` which returns my user object. So I know the service account's password is correct, permissions for it are correct and it can successfully issue queries.

But when trying to test an account from the LDAP settings profile page, I get a generic error message popup stating "Error connecting to the LDAP server:"

For the log, I am looking at the /var/opt/artifactory/artifactory-service.log file.

Here's the entry immediately following a failed 'test account' attempt:

```
2020-04-03T17:16:46.714Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [7faa71d56a50ef2b] [o.a.s.l.AbstractLdapService:67] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Error connecting to the LDAP server: 


org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: User myuseraccount failed to authenticate


    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.ArtifactoryBindAuthenticator.authenticate(ArtifactoryBindAuthenticator.java:166)


    at org.artifactory.security.ldap.LdapServiceImpl.testLdapConnection(LdapServiceImpl.java:77)


    at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.testLdapConnection(SecurityServiceImpl.java:3193)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)


    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)


    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)


    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)


    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.testLdapConnection(Unknown Source)


    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.security.ldap.ldapsettings.TestLdapSettingsService.testLdapConnection(TestLdapSettingsService.java:76)


    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.admin.security.ldap.ldapsettings.TestLdapSettingsService.execute(TestLdapSettingsService.java:63)


    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.ServiceExecutor.process(ServiceExecutor.java:38)


    at org.artifactory.rest.common.resource.BaseResource.runService(BaseResource.java:92)


    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.admin.security.ldap.LdapSettingResource.testLdapSetting(LdapSettingResource.java:90)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)


    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)


    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)


    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)


    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)


    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
2020-04-03T17:16:46.732Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [7faa71d56a50ef2b] [o.a.s.l.AbstractLdapService:68] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Error connecting to the LDAP server:
2020-04-03T17:17:57.524Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [81a5689d90762c9 ] [o.a.s.l.LdapServiceImpl:179   ] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Unexpected exception in LDAP query:for user myuseraccount vid LDAP: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]
2020-04-03T17:17:57.547Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [81a5689d90762c9 ] [o.a.s.l.LdapServiceImpl:129   ] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Couldn't find user named "myuseraccount" in ADsettings
```

From the login ui, I try to use my sam account name only I get a message above the login form stating: "Username or password is incorrect"

Here's the log entry that's generated at the time:

```
2020-04-03T17:05:12.060Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [77c816e57e51530 ] [o.a.s.l.LdapServiceImpl:179   ] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Unexpected exception in LDAP query:for user admin vid LDAP: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]
```

I am only using the sam account name for the login, not the user principal name. I am also leaving off the netbios domain name portion of the login. If I try to add in the full SAM Account name to include the domain, "companyname\myuseraccount" I get a Status 500 error page.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Although I never met such a problem, but I think you should keep fixating on `username` and `password` part. Since the log specify the exact reason ` User myuseraccount failed to authenticate`.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this question, I decided to shell into the running jcr container and copy and install the necessary rpm files and to get openldap working. Then used ldapsearch from the container to query our domain controller using the settings I had provided the artifactory UI. And viola! The issue was the bind DN. I thought the the Manager DN form field was supposed to be the full distinguished name of the binding user account used to query the directory but ldapsearch was returning object not found errors.

I changed the binding account to the service account's SAM account name ("_svcAccount") and got a result back. I've since gone back into the artifactory settings and update the Manager DN to be "_svcAccount" and everything is working.

Jfrog should change the description of the Manager DN field. A distinguished name consists of the full LDAP path to the object. Which doesn't work, at least not in my particular situation. Other Java based products we use like SonarQube, use the classic full distinguished name for the bind account. Jfrog Container Registry apparently does not.

-Update -- I ended up having to use the NetBIOS domain as part of the Manager DN account to get it to authenticate. So, instead of "_svcAccount" as the Manager DN, I had to use "mycompany\_svcAccount" as the Manager DN. However, Active Directory users do not use the NetBIOS domain when logging into the Container Registry, just the SAM account name. (i.e. "myAccount" vs. "mycompany\myAccount")

Comment: Thanks for this! We'll look into improving the documentation!